# 2nd order RC lowpass filter cut-off frequency and Transfer Function

Tags: capacitor, filter

I'm stuck trying to calculate the cut-off frequency and transfer function of the filter below.

I'm not sure how to handle the mirrored resistors on the bottom (R9, R11) or the extra resistors (R12, R13).

New to electronics so any advice would be helpful.

[image]

[Edit] I've tried remodelling the circuit like this to run through a 2 pole Rc filter calculator but not sure if it is correct

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Brute force: Just do nodal analysis on every node and solve for it. You can't use the voltage divider anymore.

Comment: Do you know reduction methods  to convert differential to single ended?

Comment: What does your simulator tell you?

Comment: Why don't you run a simulation and see what it says? Is this a question for your college coursework? Have you made any effort to solve this yourself, and if so, please show your work.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the responses. running the simulations shows me it's frequency dependant and I get a lot of attenuation at higher frequencies. At low frequencies I can use the potential divider and get the output I expect. I've made an edit to show the model I've tried simplifying too. 

For context, it's not coursework, I'm trying to map readings I'm getting on an ADC back to a current sensor.

Comment: My simulation shows it is almost an all-pass filter but with some single-ended gain but differential >20 dB attenuation to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use a simulator to find the equivalent circuit when removing the differential configuration:

[image]

Once you have a working equivalent schematic (same ac and dc responses), then you can start the analysis of this second-order filter. I will neglect the 6-pF contribution which comes across the 2.2-nF capacitor:

[image]

The easiest and fastest path here is to apply the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs as described in my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371). Without writing a single line of algebra, just by determining time constants by inspection, you can determine the transfer function of this circuit easily. The maths details are given below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the extremly detailed answer!

Comment: No problem at all, glad if this is helpful. You can download from my page a seminar I taught in 2016, [APEC 2016](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf) which offers a smooth introduction on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I extended the range 20 Hz to 24 kHz to show the single ended nodes A,B,  V+,V-  a differential load with one redundant R removed.

[My simulation.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsI4A5IDYCcS4BYDMZ1sBGAdgMQgTkoFMBaIogKAHcRtskQAmOVdzjyRcwrAV0bdxIIh3BMA5om4S5cFTNQRtTAMbTZ2ZaqMRu9IlNyRu6HKTCosqbt2xSw0MM30cuvfnV-PnAeCykiNDAkME5UVDgSXCQiXBISKBhmNmSjAJBcbjMQ0RykI0MCopk5UoM5XJrTJgAneqM-HhKZGJhWquL%20fPyIImo%20tsLRuXzK0fHRNuGQonQpEZlx-tm5VYjazb79RsrGje4bWCvrmFx6dBk0JCSnbDAVNyJYhE8spgcZGsmpppkZcDwzG8YIgoMwlDg8iEETwSB55Eo9l1%20JjuKjQosCrhsSR%20LgiRCRD1YHoscDlvwINhIGQbjciPd2GhsOhvNhUCTUYKPF5mG0grTkRt2QxuGJOvkziUmEUMp1JNIYuwQAA1AA6AAdlWBVYIVFxOlMtdq6EaMjtEfx0PwjABBW20%20kFWJagBCTAAHuwsDxGCAtP5ZFqviAADy6gCOuoAzgBDAAmACsAK5JgAuyZYAEtcwALZMAWwA9jmaAWSzQaAAbJiVmph0xB%20Iw363HkuH48NvgxuVhTJpMsBv65MAIgAbpXG7mUwpa0mk9WWroaDOWyH26E3phu5AiKEz3rDa3XAfGQQuD9T%20edTbr%20DUB2jw-YTJB25Qm6rZcB%20h73jwkCPrAuB9rwf4gFwuBMEAA)

[image]

What are your expectations?